# HHVM 3.0 / Hack with Nginx cannot access file in directory with 770 permissions on Ubuntu 13.10 while having group membership

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, hiphop, hhvm

I have **nginx** set up to use the HipHop VM version 3.0 in fast-cgi mode.  Some facts:

1. I'm running on Ubuntu 13.10
2. The nginx and hhvm  run as the user `www-data`.
3. The user www-data is in the group `fooers`
4. The server root for nginx is a directory `/srv/foo` with a single `index.php` file in it
5. The group ownership of `/srv/foo` is the group `fooers`
6. `/srv/foo` permissions are set to `770`

When I try to view this page, I get a 404 not found, but no errors logged in either hhvm or nginx logs.  However, if I change permissions to `775` on `/srv/foo` the page gets served by the `hhvm` and `nginx` perfectly as expected.

Also, if I change the ***default*** group for the www-data user to be the fooers group, it works with 770 permissions.  It only seems to fail when it's not the default group for the user.

What's the issue?!?!? Does anyone know why the hhvm/nginx running as a user www-data with group access to a directory is unable to access when permissions are 770?

To confirm my sanity and ensure my groups and permissions are as I think they are, after starting services, I run

```
$> ps -aux
```

I see as expected an hhvm process and the nginx processes running as `www-data`:

```
www-data  3484 .... /usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini --user www-data --mode daemon -vPidFile=/var/run/hhvm/pid
www-data  3617 ... nginx: worker process
```

When I check the groups I see:

```
$> groups www-data
www-data : www-data fooers
```

When I check the directory, I can confirm 100% access to group and owner:

```
$> ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Mar 30 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root   4096 Mar 30 11:52 ..
drwxrwx---  2 root fooers 4096 Mar 30 15:39 foo
```

If I check the contents of the file as the `www-data` user I am allowed in:

```
$> sudo -u www-data ls -al /srv/foo
total 12
drwxrwx--- 2 root fooers 4096 Mar 30 15:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Mar 30 15:57 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root fooers   38 Mar 30 15:39 index.php
```

If I try the above with a user not in the fooers group, it fails.

Here is my `/etc/hhvm/server.ini`:

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific

hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
```

I really hope this isn't something silly and obvious I overlooked...

Here is my nginx location block for the web root:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root /srv/foo
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/foo$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Please post your /etc/hhvm/server.ini. I have an nginx with hhvm-gastcgi too, but with `ps -aux` it looks like this: `/usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/server.hdf --user www-data --mode daemon -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9010`

Comment: @PKeidel The `ps` got a little cut off.  I'm setting the type  to fastcgi and port to 9000 in the `ini` file.

Comment: @Pkeidel Also, I'm just running the new HHVM 3.0 in fastcgi mode, no `hhvm-fastcgi` package anymore

Comment: I think hat hhvm-fastcgi package only creates a /etc/init.d/hhvm-fastcgi.

Comment: You wrote that your nginx web root is `/srv/foo`. But your hhvm repo.central.path is pointing at `/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc`. So you have to chmod this file/directory path and not /srv/foo/*. Have you tried that yet? And when you make an nmap port scan, is your port `9000` listed as open?

Comment: @PKeidel Thanks for the advice.  I think `hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc` is the place where it caches the processed bytcode--not the locaiton of the php source files, so it shouldn't be affected as `/srv/foo` is location for my php source files.  Also, I verified HHVM is listining at 9000

Comment: Where have you set `/srv/foo` as your hhvm www directory?

Comment: @PKeidel In my nginx configuration.  I'll add the location block to the OP

Comment: Hi, I just tested HHVM 3.0.1 and it worked with default settings. I installed a new Ubuntu 13.10 with hhvm via apt-get. HHVM was started by `/usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini --user www-data --mode daemon -vPidFile=/var/run/hhvm/pid`. The server.ini is the same as yours. Maybe a chmod 777 for all the logfiles could help?!?

Comment: @PKeidel thanks for the feedback, I'll try 3.0.1 this weekend.  yes, when I chown the files to be group that is the primary group for www-data it works fine or if I 777 everything.  The only issue owner is not www-data and the group ownership is not the primary group for www-data.  This shouldn't be the case--all groups that www-data has access for should work for it with 770 permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with HHVM.  I've added a ticket to fix this in there project.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change your config file, there is no SourceRoot in yours. Some of my confs are overriden by start parameters.

Have a look at them here: `/usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/server.hdf --user www-data --mode daemon -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9010`

```
PidFile = /var/run/hhvm/pid

Server {
  Port = 82
  SourceRoot = /var/www/main/
  DefaultDocument = index.php
}

#AdminServer {
#    Port = 9088
#    ThreadCount = 1
#    Password = xxx
#}

Eval {
    Jit = true
    JitWarmupRequests = 5
}

Log {
  Level = Error
  AlwaysLogUnhandledExceptions = true
  RuntimeErrorReportingLevel = 8191
  UseLogFile = true
  UseSyslog = false
  File = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
  Access {
    * {
      File = /var/log/hhvm/access.log
      Format = %h %l %u % t \"%r\" %>s %b
    }
  }
}

#Repo {
#  Central {
#    Path = /var/run/hhvm.hhbc.sq3
#  }
#}

#include "/usr/share/hhvm/hdf/static.mime-types.hdf"
StaticFile {
  FilesMatch {
    * {
      pattern = .*\.(dll|exe)
      headers {
        * = Content-Disposition: attachment
      }
    }
  }
  Extensions : StaticMimeTypes
}

MySQL {
  TypedResults = false
}
```

Comment: This is the in old `.hdf`.  While it's still supporting, as of HHVM 3.0 there moving to the `.ini` format shown in my post.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. My production server still runs with the latest 2.X version. In the next view days I want to try 3.0 too. I let you now when I got things running (or not).

Comment: You actually use HHVM in production ? That's pretty cool. URL ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't show it. It's an internal page for a customer, they are using it for managing orders, customers and so on. On the server is also running a piwik, but the piwik dashboard isn't working with hhvm. But the inserts work ;) Dashboard is served from a apache on another port.